# How are you supposed to use the silk icon set when the image is about 1mb?

Tags: css

I assume people don't just use the current icon image, since it's a very large file. Do you generally use photoshop/illustrator to chop the file down to exactly what you need? Or is there a simple tool to more easily do this? I saw one article where the author had cut down the image to 65k (http://www.thegooglecache.com/uncategorized/silk-css-using-css-clipping-and-optimized-silk-image/). But that also seems a little large to me for a usable icon set. What's the best practice here?

Also, is the silk icon set available through a cdn somewhere (something like google's ajax api)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ahhh, the [preview](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/previews/index_abc.png) is 1mb in size but each icon can be used individually if you download the pack

Comment: also, i don't know of any CDN but it's a bloody good idea -  a TypeKit for icons would be awesome

Comment: Right, I see what you mean. I feel a little foolish now. :-) 

For anyone stumbling on this post from google, you still don't want to serve these suckers individually, but that doesn't mean you want to use the giant preview png. Instead you just need to pick the ones you want/need, then turn them into an image sprite using your favorite css sprite tool. I highly recommend this tool. 

http://spritegen.website-performance.org/

You just zip up the files you want, and it'll generate the appropriate css for you.

Answer (score 1):

Each individual icon is less than 1kb. I would suggest just using them individually.
If you intend to use a large number of different icons, you can add them all to one file, so it is all downloaded in one request, and then use CSS, as he does in the link, to choose the icon you want.

It sounds like you might be using the preview image, don't do that, click on the download link.